# The long expression could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to execute this query

```
    var userAndLovedOnesQuery = await (from uq in _context.Users
    
                                                           where uq.SubjectId == request.SubjectId
                                                           select new
                                                           {
                                                               user =  (from p in _context.Persons
                                                                       where p.Id == uq.PersonId
                                                                       select p)
                                                                   .Include(x => x.PrimaryPhoneNumber).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken),
                                                               lovedones = (from profileGroup in _context.ProfileGroups where profileGroup.UserId == uq.Id
                                                                            join profileGroupDetail in _context.ProfileGroupDetails on profileGroup.Id equals profileGroupDetail.ProfileGroupId
                                                                            join person in _context.Persons on profileGroupDetail.PersonId equals person.Id
                                                                            select person).Include(u => u.PrimaryPhoneNumber)
                                                                   .ToListAsync(cancellationToken),
                                                           }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

and I am getting this error.

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Person>()
    .Where(p => p.Id == u.PersonId)
    .Include(x => x.PrimaryPhoneNumber)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(__cancellationToken_1)' could no## Heading ##t be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: The problem isn't the length, it's the query itself. For starters, it's misusing EF Core. LINQ-to-Entities isn't a replacement for SQL. It's EF Core's job to generate queries with JOINs from the relations between entities. The queries you use will be translated to SQL which means you can't use methods and constructs that aren't possible in SQL. And finally, `Include` is *only* meant to eagerly load related entities. It doesn't create relations or JOINs

Comment: In this case, if a `User` is related to a `Person`, there should be a `User.Person` property. There's no reason to write a query that loads that single user. There's no need for a query, `Include` or `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Same with ProfileGroups - there should be a `User.ProfileGroups` property, a `ProfileGroup.Details` and a `ProfileGroupDetail.Person` property. You wouldn't need any joins in that case

Comment: Please take the time to properly format the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.ToListAsync(cancellationToken)` with `.ToList()` and `.FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken)` with `.FirstOrDefault()`. It is wrong to use `async` methods in projection.

```cs
var userAndLovedOnesQuery = await (
    from uq in _context.Users
    where uq.SubjectId == request.SubjectId
    select new
    {
        user = (from p in _context.Persons
                where p.Id == uq.PersonId
                select p)
            .Include(x => x.PrimaryPhoneNumber)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        lovedones = (from profileGroup in _context.ProfileGroups where profileGroup.UserId == uq.Id
                    join profileGroupDetail in _context.ProfileGroupDetails on profileGroup.Id equals profileGroupDetail.ProfileGroupId
                    join person in _context.Persons on profileGroupDetail.PersonId equals person.Id
                    select person).Include(u => u.PrimaryPhoneNumber)
            .ToList(),
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```